# type Future<List<Item>> is not subtype of List error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My function defination is below

```
Future<List<Item>> fetchGitUsers() async {
final response = await http.get('https://');

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  GitUsers gitUser =  GitUsers.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  return gitUser.items;
 }
```

} / Function end

```
class GitUsers {
    List<Item> items;
 }


class ... extends State<SearchController> {

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    gitUsers = fetchGitUsers() as List<Item>;
  }
}
```

But I am getting below error on emulator screen..

***[image: type Future<List<Item>> is not subtype of List] in type cast.***

Comment: Since `fetchGitUsers()` is async the response is not `List<Item>` but `Future<List<Item>>`. You can use a FutureBuilder to display the data.

Comment: Post a full and more detailed code so we can help you.

Comment: may be you forgot to add await where you are calling, so also add code where you are calling.

Comment: posted more snapshot of code

Comment: Try to change your function to `Future<void>` then set state of `gitUser` inside the function instead of returning it. After that in your initState call your function like this `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){fetchGitUsers})`

Comment: one good solution... but how if I want to test some module by checking there return value probably not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add `await`

Try this

```
void getUsers() async{
   gitUsers = await fetchGitUsers();
}

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUsers();
  }
}
```

If you want to use the git users in a UI (e.g ListView), consider using FutureBuilder.

Like this

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: fetchGitUsers(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

    return ListView();
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks for code snap... working!!.. I am just stated Flutter so digging it...